# Why doesn't ajax load() work after second and third call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I've been trying to get my three update same time when I click button to get update it will count for new feeds, notifications and messages. I've tried by using `setInterval( "getupdate()", 10000 )` too, to get update automatically every 10 seconds but doesn't work for second and third divs.

Or because Ajax doesn't support many `load()` call?

Now, I have no idea how should I do and need your helps. Thanks.

Javascript

```
</script>

function getupdate(){
    $('#newsfeed').load('getnewsfeed.php');
    $('#notify').load('getnewnoti.php');
    $('#message').load('getnewmessage.php');
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="getupdate()" class="btn btn-primary">Get Update</button>
<div id="newsfeed"></div>
<div id="notify"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Or checked that the response has a value?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and also move `$('#notify').load('getnewnoti.php')` and `$('#message').load('getnewmessage.php')` as the first, and it works well.

Comment: Please show the rest of your page. Invalid HTML (including duplicate IDs or missing tags) will cause the matches to fail.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who attempting to help me, my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a problem with concurrent ajax calls, you can always load them in sequence:

```
function getupdate(){
    $('#newsfeed').load('getnewsfeed.php', function(){
        $('#notify').load('getnewnoti.php', function(){
            $('#message').load('getnewmessage.php');
        });
    });
}
```

*If this does not help, we need to see the rest of your page too please* :)

You also need to check whether *all three* server methods are returning something and not an error.